# change ruby version with rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I have just installed rbenv and try to use it, I have unistalled rvm.
I am now trying to use 2.3.3 version of ruby.

```
rbenv local
2.3.3
rbenv global
2.3.3

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

Comment: https://devhints.io/rbenv#using-versions

Comment: I have already set the version rbenv global 2.3.3 but ruby -v still gives me 2.3.7

Comment: You might have incorrect PATH settings in your shell profile. Maybe needs cleanup after removing rvm. Read rbenv docs about PATH. You may check PATH with `echo $PATH` command. `.rbenv/shims` must be there. `which ruby` command might also help.

Comment: @Petran does rbenv now work for you?